# .ssh Directory has no id files after installing ssh service

Tags: ssh

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and activated ssh service using

```
sudo apt install ssh
```

I tried to connect to my Ubuntu from my Windows using ssh via putty and it worked.
putty asked to trust Ubuntu's key and everything is good.

But if I go to Ubuntu and try to see the public and private keys that were generated when installing the ssh service, they aren't in the `~/.ssh/` directory.

Can anyone explain it, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between connecting with SSH and generating SSH public and private keys. *Be aware that the terminology in your question (public and private keys, "id files", `~/.ssh/`) lead to thinking about user generated SSH keypairs.*

The directory you're referring to (`~/.ssh/`) is for user generated SSH keypairs, `known_hosts` file etc., and installing SSH in itself will not generate a user keypair. If you want to connect with SSH keypairs from Windows, you need to do the following:

- Create a SSH keypair on your Windows machine (off-topic here, but on-topic on [Superuser](https://superuser.com))
- Install the public key you generated on Windows on your Ubuntu machine

Here is a [Q&A on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password/) that details how to setup SSH keys on Windows for use with PuTTY, and [another one](https://superuser.com/questions/197489/where-does-putty-store-known-hosts-information-on-windows) about why and how the keys are stored.

However, if you're referring to the SSH host keys that are generated when installing SSH, those are located inside `/etc/ssh`, and can be listed with this command:

```
$ ls -la /etc/ssh/ssh_host*
-rw------- 1 root root 1373 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  597 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  492 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  169 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  399 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   89 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 2590 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  561 May  8  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The public host key is saved on the client machine (as `known_hosts`) to verify the identity of the remote machine and mark the connection as "trusted". On Ubuntu, known hosts are saved in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (refer to [Superuser](https://superuser.com) when it comes to Windows).

Comment: This question is not about connecting with ssh keys. Anytime you connect to something with ssh for the first times, some keys are generated. Even if you connect using a password. The question is what are these keys and where they are located. I am interested in an answer too. My guess is that the keys are at Windows side.

Comment: Yeah, they would be on Windows, and thus off-topic here.

Comment: The OP is probably talking about the server's *host key*

Comment: @ArturMeinild It is not really off-topic. Let's assume we are connecting from one Ubuntu to another. An answer about host keys would be useful.

Comment: Added location of SSH host keys

Comment: The OP may also wish to know why they were asked to accept the key and [Where does Putty store known_hosts information on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/197489/where-does-putty-store-known-hosts-information-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you guys. I got the answer and an good explanation. Thank you @ArturMeinild for the explanation again.